# Cloning a call leads to callback being called off the main thread

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

All calls and callbacks work fine. I just have an issue where I clone and retry a call within the callback (with the same callback) due to a http error code.

```
public static abstract class MyCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, retrofit2.Response<T> response) {
        Timber.d("is this the main thread %b", Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper());
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            //success handling
        } else {
            if (response.code() == 406) {
                // remedy reason for failure
                call.clone().enqueue(MyCallback.this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        Timber.e("onFailure %s", t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This gives:

```
is this the main thread true
is this the main thread false
is this the main thread false
is this the main thread false
is this the main thread false
[looping]
```

I played around with other/new callbacks, starting a new call, etc. Only when I clone the call the callback is invoked off the main thread.
The actual problem that arises is, that I can't change the UI after the successfully retried call.

Using Retrofit 2.0.1

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it's not running on main thread? Have you tried changing the UI and got an exception?

Comment: @muratgu Yes. I only stumbled across it because I got the "views can only be edited from the thread they were created on" exception. Only then did I incl. those looper checks for the logs..

Comment: I think you found a bug either in retrofit or okhttp. I just confirmed that the executing thread on callback is not the main thread if the call is created via the clone method before enqueue.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug in retrofit. Jake Wharton just created a PR for this:

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1716